# How does block validators communicate each other?

Tags: consensus, dpos

In the process of validating a block by block producers(at least 15 block producers should validate and agree – knowledge taken by technical paper). How can they communicate with each other that they are validated a block and agreed?

Did they follow the YES/NO strategy or they share more information of block they validate?

Answer (score 0):

All the process of communicating and validating blocks is done in the eosio code by the concensus

“A consensus mechanism is a fault-tolerant mechanism that is used in computer and blockchain systems to achieve the necessary agreement on a single data value or a single state of the network among distributed processes or multi-agent systems.”

You can see the codes for the chain they are running there: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/libraries/chain